# Why is distance to an object inversely proportional to image size when using perspective projection?

Tags: optics

[In this PDF](https://www.cse.unr.edu/%7Ebebis/CS791E/Notes/PerspectiveProjection.pdf), it says the following about perspective projection:

> The distance to an object is inversely proportional to its image size.

What causes this equasion? Why is it inversely proportional and not something else?

Comment: Maybe you should be a little bit more specific... What exactly do you mean with "something else"? Regarding the fact that the image size is inversely proportional to the distance I think you can derive a connection between the two if you consider the fact that you use linear projections of the image on the projection plane through the origin ("pinhole").

Comment: Doesn't this have more to do with how an object's size is inversely proportional to the distance it is? I don't think it has as much to do with perspective projection, and more to do with this geometric fact. If you like I can give you a geometric explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the title of you post should be, *Why is **distance to an object** inversely proportional to image size when using perspective projection?*

[image]

Triangle $ABC$ and $A'B'C$ are similar so $\dfrac zf = \dfrac{r}{r'} \Rightarrow z \propto \dfrac {1}{r'}\Rightarrow \text {object distance} \propto \dfrac {1} {\text{image size}}$ if $r$ and $f$ are kept constant.